# Inequality on Independent Random Variables Extending to Their Range

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $S$ and $\xi$ be independent real-valued $\mathbb{P}$-random variables and let

$$f(S(\omega), \xi(\omega)) \leq g(S(\omega), \xi(\omega)), \quad \text{almost all $\omega\in\Omega$}$$

for some real-valued measurable functions $f$ and $g$.

Assume that the distribution $\mathbb{P}_S$ of $S$ has a Lebesgue-density. Does it follow for Lebesgue-almost all $s\in\textrm{supp}(\mathbb{P}_S$) that
$$f(s, \xi)\leq g(s, \xi)\quad \text{$\mathbb{P}$-a.s.}?$$

Comment: Do you mean "for all $s$ a.s." or "a.s. for all $s$"?

Comment: @d.k.o. I meant that for all $s$ in the support of the distribution of $S$ it would be for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$ the inequality $f(s, \xi(\omega)) \leq g(s, \xi(\omega))$.
Please feel free, however, to relax my assumptions in any way you see fit. For Lebesgue-measure almost all $s$ in the support of the distribution would be fine as well...

Comment: Take $N$ with $P_S(N)=0$ and set $g(s, \cdot)=f(s, \cdot)$ for $s\in N^c$ and $g(s, \cdot)=f(s, \cdot)-1$ for $s\in N$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks, but one would need to add $N\subseteq\textrm{supp}(\mathbb{P}_S)$, right? I will make my question more precise...

Comment: No. Take for example the case when $(S,\xi)\sim U[0,1]^2$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Still, $N$ would have Lebesgue measure zero then, right? I would like to exclude that case as well... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required inequality holds for $P_S$ almost all $s$ because
\begin{align}
0&=\mathsf{P}(f(S,\xi)>g(S,\xi)) \\
&=\int\mathsf{P}(f(s,\xi)>g(s,\xi))\,dP_S(s).
\end{align}
Otherwise, since
$$
\{\mathsf{P}(f(s,\xi)>g(s,\xi))>0\}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{\mathsf{P}(f(s,\xi)>g(s,\xi))\ge n^{-1}\},
$$
there exist $n\ge 1$ such that $P_S(A_n)>0$ with $A_n:=\{\mathsf{P}(f(s,\xi)>g(s,\xi))\ge n^{-1}\}$, which implies that
$$
\int\mathsf{P}(f(s,\xi)>g(s,\xi))\,dP_S(s)\ge n^{-1}P_S(A_n)>0.
$$